# GroupBy and limitTo does not work together ? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, group-by, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I googled very hard but can't find solution for this.

I want to use groupBy and limitTo together  but its does not work.

My code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in items | groupBy: 'group' | limitTo: limit"> ... </ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.limit = 2; // its dinamic value

$scope.items = [
   {name: "Audi", group:1},
   {name: "BMW", group:1},
   {name: "Dodge", group:2},
   {name: "Fiat", group:2},
   {name: "Ford", group:3}
];
```

If **they are seperate, then its work**, 
but **when they are together, it doesn't work**.

**How i can fix that ?**

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to add a `toArray` filter to convert the groupBy result back to an array for limitTo:

`<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in items | groupBy: 'group' | toArray | limitTo: limit"> ... </ul>`

Comment: Its doesnt help

Comment: oh, I see. It did work for me..  note that your `value` then is an array of items. What are you trying to do with them? I just printed with  {{key}} : {{value}} and got  ```0 : [{"name":"Audi","group":1},{"name":"BMW","group":1}]
1 : [{"name":"Dodge","group":2},{"name":"Fiat","group":2}]
```